# Como contar itens iguais de 5 colunas diferentes?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela [assim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD0sL.jpg). A tabela guarda o registro de presenças ( **P**) e faltas ( **F**). Preciso contar, por exemplo, quantas presenças e quantas faltas um determinado código tem.

Comment: Você passou também o idUsuario em questão? Você poderia fazer assim oh... presenca -> id, idUsuario, dia, presenca ... dessa forma, cada vez que tiver presença confirmada, registra no banco de dados, e você apenas faz um group by idUsuario e um where presenca = 1 (presente) 2 (faltou) e consegue saber a quantidade...

Comment: Esta tabela monitora apenas usa semana? de cinco dias? ou você quer monitorar o mes todo?

Answer (score 2):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

## Estrutura da tabela.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `frequencia` (
  `idFrequencia` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idUsuario` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `diaSemana` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `presenca` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idFrequencia`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `frequencia` 
(`idFrequencia`, `idUsuario`, `diaSemana`, `presenca`) 
VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2, 1),
(3, 1, 3, 2),
(4, 1, 4, 2),
(5, 1, 5, 1);
```

E então faria um SQL:

```
SELECT count(idFrequencia) as qtdFalta FROM frequencia WHERE idUSuario = '1' GROUP BY presenca = '2';
```

Para conseguir saber os resultados. É uma opção!